# C++ WINAPI Smooth Scrolling

Tags: c++, windows, scroll

I am developing VS2019 Windows C++ application where I need to implement smooth scrolling using a swipe gesture. Think using a touchscreen to swipe to the left (but I'm not using a touchscreen). I would like this to scroll over any open window that is currently focused. I am currently using the following code:

`mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -maxDistance * val, 0);`

where `maxDistance = 35` (amount to scroll) and `val` is a easing out function `1 - std::pow(1 - x, 4)`.

This is kind of what I need, but it's still staggering the scroll distance and it looks very choppy. Can anyone advise me on how to create a smooth scrolling experience?

Comment: perhaps you should try using WM_VSCROLL instead, wheel scrolls on X lines or pages

Comment: Another option is to use the value you're currently computing as a target. Then, at every frame interpolate the current scroll position towards the target. That way, when the user suddenly scroll, the windows starts moving smoothly and continues for, say, 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @user7860670 WM_VSCROLL requires a window handle, which is not ideal. mouse_event does not, and just scrolls whatever the mouse is currently over.

Comment: @Jeffrey I'll give interpolation a try - I currently do that for cursor movement as well and it makes it look super smooth.